# Onclick on normal button is submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

**SCENARIO**

I have a `java` JSP view with a long form. This was working nice. I can submit my form by pressing enter in any input field or with submit button.

**NEW REQUIREMENT**

In a part, I must add buttons to replace some `<label>` for `<input>` to allow editing, nothing hard.

**WHAT I TRIED**

This part of the view is created dinamically, cause number of lines depends of the data introduced by user, this parts creates each line:

```
resultadoHTML += "  <div class='row col-lg-12 col-xs-12' style='margin-bottom: 30px;text-align: left;'>";
resultadoHTML += "      <label class='col-lg-3 col-xs-12 control-label' >" + nomCalidad + "</label>";
resultadoHTML += "      <div class='col-lg-5 col-xs-8'>";
resultadoHTML += "          <input type='text' class='form-control' value='"+valor+"' id='calidadCatId' maxlength='30' required='true' />";
resultadoHTML += "      </div>";

resultadoHTML += "      <div class='col-lg-2 col-xs-3' id='ccc" + parts[1] + "'>";
resultadoHTML += "          <label class='control-label' id='unidadCCC" + parts[1] + "' >" + parts[4] + "</label>";
resultadoHTML += "      </div>";
resultadoHTML += "      <div class='col-lg-2 col-xs-1'>";
resultadoHTML += "          <button id='eCCC" + parts[1] + "' class='btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign'></span></button>";
resultadoHTML += "      </div>";
resultadoHTML += "  </div>";
```

**Resulting HTML of the button**

```
 <button id="eCCC5" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></button>
```

**PROBLEM**

When I use `onclick` to define a function in the new button, this function is called, but after, the `click` event of the submit button is **ALSO** called and I dont know why... But as you can see in the code, even when i **DON'T** catch any event in the button the `click` event of the form is called.

**OTHER INFO**

*FORM/BUTTON DEFINITION*

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post"
    commandName="contratMercan" action="../contratos/contratosubmit"
    name="formulario" id="edicionContrato">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="edicionContrato">                               
    <spring:message ... />  // omitted info 
</button>
```

*SUBMIT FUNCTION*

```
$("#edicionContrato").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = this;

    // checks and workarounds...

    form.submit();
});
```

Any idea why could happen? Maybe dinamically introduced `HTML` code has some mistake and brokes `javascript` or `html` after?

Comment: You can avoid that problem using ('#yourbutton').on('click', function(){ your code }), do you know what I mean? I can type a properly answer with the submit if you need it

Comment: It won't prevent the form from submitting. You have to use `.on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /* rest of the code */  })`

Comment: i cant use `on('click'` names are created dinamically as you can see... it was a silly mistake not defining the type of the button

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you use the `<button>` element without specifying a type, it [defaults to `type="submit"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type).  You need to specify it as `type="button"` to stop it submitting the form:

```
<button type="button" id="eCCC5" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: my goodness, I never knew about this... so if we have 3 buttons, they all have to be set to `type="button"`. That's quite verbose. I guess it could have been defaulted to `type="button"`, but obviously inside of the form, it is defaulted to `type="submit"`

Answer (score 2):

If you have button with attribute `type="submit"`, clicking on submit will send whole form. I think if you add attribute `type="button"` or just delete it. Form probably won't send if you click on button or push `ENTER` being in input.

Comment: Great answer. I upvoted it, but I accepted James one cause it was some seconds earlier... Thanks Mike, ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to place the button element outside the FORM would help but it depends on your requirements. If you need to put that button inside the FORM then you've to mention type="button"