# Using inheritance in a constructor

Tags: java, android, inheritance, constructor

I have a `BaseActivity class` and another Activity that extends `BaseActivity`

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity {
```

I also have a class that as part of its constructor takes `BaseActivity` as its param

```
public class MyTask {

    BaseActivity cb_activity;

public void MyTask(BaseActivity activity){..
```

But when i try to invoke MyTask's constructor from LoginActivity it doesn't seem to accept it as a "BaseActivity" and wants me to make a separate constructor.. is there a way around this with out creating a second constructor?

```
MyTask loginTask= new MyTask(this);
```

Comment: is this your constructor `public void MyTask(BaseActivity activity){` ???

Comment: `public void MyTask(` should be just `public MyTask(`

Comment: When you put a return statement it makes it a method, not a constructor.  Constructors don't return.

Comment: omg.. i need sleep.. lol that was just silly type

Comment: thanks folks.. stupid muscle memory

Answer (score 1):

This is not a [valid Constructor declaration](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html)

```
public void MyTask(BaseActivity activity){..
```

you must declare like this:

```
public MyTask(BaseActivity activity){..
```

Comment: i can't believe i missed that

Comment: it happens to me also.... [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876955/onclick-on-normal-button-is-submitting-form) xDDDD