# Why is my onSubmit handler being called when I click a button that is NOT 'type="submit"'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, onsubmit

Debugging an issue with a basic TODO list app that I am building in React/TS with Formik.

**Main problem is that when I click my delete project button, it is calling the onSubmit handler when it shouldn't be**, and of course gives the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tasks')
at updateProjectNameInState"
...which of course it can't, because it is supposed to be deleted. I never intended for the onSubmit to happen here but for some reason it does.

Could it be because I am calling the `props.handleClick()` function inside my delete function? (This handleClick function is meant to update state in the parent component to unmount the form component.)

**Formik Component Code:**

*(pasting the whole code for context but buttons in question are found near the bottom)*

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import { AllContext } from "../App";
import { Formik, Field, Form, FormikHelpers, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
//schemas
import { conditionalEditProjectNameSchema } from "../schemas";
import * as yup from "yup";

//types
interface Values {
    projectName: string;
  }


export default function EditProjectForm(props: any){
    const {allProjects, selectedProject, currentTask} = React.useContext(AllContext);
    const [allProjectsCopy, setAllProjects] = allProjects;
    

    function updateProjectNameInState(data: Values){
      //changes only the project name in state.
      //keeps everything else, including tasks

      //create a copy of the state
      let newAllProjects = {...allProjectsCopy};

      //grab old project tasks using prop
      let oldProjectTasks = newAllProjects[`${props.oldProjectName}`].tasks;

      //delete old project in the object
      delete newAllProjects[`${props.oldProjectName}`];

      //add project with updated name back to new state object
      let updatedProject = new Project(`${data.projectName}`);
      updatedProject.tasks = oldProjectTasks;
      newAllProjects[`${data.projectName}`] = updatedProject;

      //set state equal to new object
      setAllProjects(newAllProjects); 
    }

    function deleteProject(){
      //create a copy of the state
      let newAllProjects = {...allProjectsCopy};
      //delete old project in the object
      delete newAllProjects[`${props.oldProjectName}`];
      //set state equal to new object
      setAllProjects(newAllProjects);
      props.handleclick(); 
    }

    class Project {
        title: string;
        tasks: {};

        constructor(title: string){
            this.title = title;
            this.tasks = {};
        }
    }


    let editProjectSchema = conditionalEditProjectNameSchema(allProjectsCopy);


    return (
        <div className="edit-form-project-name">
          <button onClick={props.handleClick} className='close-btn' aria-label="Close Form">X</button>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              projectName: props.oldProjectName
            }}
            validationSchema={editProjectSchema}
            onSubmit={(values: Values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }: FormikHelpers<Values>) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
             updateProjectNameInState(values);
            
                setSubmitting(false);
              }, 500);
              resetForm();
            }}
            
          >
            <Form className="Form formik-form">
              <label htmlFor="projectName">Edit Project Name</label>
              <span className="edit-input-container flexbox">
                <Field className='Field text-input' id="projectName" name="projectName" placeholder="Give your project a new name" />
                <button title="confirm changes" type="submit">&#9989;</button>
                <button title="delete project" onClick={deleteProject} className="delete-btn">&#128465;</button>
              </span>
              <ErrorMessage name="projectName">{msg => <div className="error-feedback error-msg-edit-project">{msg}</div>}</ErrorMessage>
              
              
            </Form>
          </Formik>
        </div>
      );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Onclick on normal button is submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876955/onclick-on-normal-button-is-submitting-form)

Answer (score 5):

By default, buttons inside a form act as submit buttons. To avoid this, explicitly set the type to `"button"`.

```
<button type="button" title="delete project" onClick={deleteProject} className="delete-btn">&#128465;</button>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I looked for similar issues and I was sure there was a simple solution like this, but most of the results were all some degree of: "onSubmit button NOT being called when I want it too", wheras I didn't see any of the opposite issue: "Why is onSubmit being called when I DON'T want it to?".